# Processing Dictionary based data values in Panda

Tags: python

I pulled a historical listing of exchange rates into a Panda data frame through JSON.

```
date_index                                              rates   base
===================================================================
2019-01-02  {'CAD': 0.3294204895, 'HKD': 1.89202246, 'ISK'...   MYR
2019-01-03  {'CAD': 0.3273500638, 'HKD': 1.8903445342, 'IS...   MYR
2019-01-04  {'CAD': 0.3253937927, 'HKD': 1.8962552541, 'IS...   MYR
2019-01-07  {'CAD': 0.324265252, 'HKD': 1.9029602122, 'ISK...   MYR
2019-01-08  {'CAD': 0.3232099972, 'HKD': 1.9057445859, 'IS...   MYR
```

The values in `df['rates']` are in dictionary form and I need to either:

1. convert it into MultiIndex
2. convert the keys and values into individual columns

How should I go about it?

@Prune , I am not used to any editing on Stack but here goes:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':

    url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/history?start_at=2019-01-01 end_at=2020-04-15&base=MYR"
    #url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=MYR"
    response = requests.get(url)
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    df = pd.DataFrame(json_data, columns=['rates', 'base', 'start_at', 'end_at'])
    df = df.reset_index()
    df['date_index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['index'])
    df.set_index('date_index', inplace=True)
    del df['index']
```

Basically I want to separate the keys in 'rates' and turn them into columns

or maybe :

have 'rates' as a multiindex

Comment: You should work through tutorials on the applicable coding topics.  Then, when you have some partially-working code with a *specific*, reproducible problem, you may well have a viable Stack Overflow question.

Comment: It might help if you try converting it to an list `data = pandas.values.tolist()`

Comment: I tried that but I was unable to merge the frames properly. I tried reading thought panda  documentatio and examples bit i couldn't find one that relates to manipulating dictionaries directly in the dataframe output.

Comment: sorry @Lore , I was never great at describing things.

Comment: Just joking, no problems!